# Why does my pointer doesn't want to be dereferenced?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, integer

Actually I am registering Callback to lower layer of code from upper layer.

So In a c "config file" file I have this :

```
typedef enum eActivationType
{
    TYPE_A = 0,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C,
}ActivationType_t;

typedef struct Callbacks_s
{
    void (*OnJoin)(ActivationType_t Mode);
}NemeusCallbacks_t;

static Callbacks_t Callbacks = {
        .OnJoin = OnJoin,
        .//I have other callbacks here but I the first one works the other will work
};

static Params_t Params = {
    .DefaultActivationType = TYPE_A,
    //other params
}

Callbacks_t* GetCallbacks(void)
{
    return &Callbacks;
}

Params_t* GetParams(void)
{
    return &Params;
}
```

From the main file I call

```
typedef void (*OnJoin)(ActivationType_t Mode);

static OnJoinRequest JoinCB;

void Nemeus_Init_ReceiveCallback(OnJoin joinCB)
{
    JoinCB = joinCB;
}
```

And then when I want to use my register callback I can't

```
...
    if( 0 == memcmp(&addr, temp_uint8_array, sizeof(addr)) && NULL != JoinCB)
    {
       JoinCB(&(*(GetParams())->DefaultActivationType));
    }
...
```

The error I have is : `invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')`.

I think it deals with the adress of GetParams that I want to dereference as adress are store in int.

It is quite complicated for me to understand whats going on but as I am a begginer I want to learn.

---

I thought that by writing this `*(GetParams())` , I can acceed the structure and then by writing this `&(*(GetParams())->DefaultActivationType)` I can pass the adress of the structur field to the callback

Comment: How exactly does `&(*(GetParams())->` make any sense? Instead of writing completely obscure stuff like that, did you try `GetParams()->DefaultActivationType`? In case you get the same error then, well as already mentioned when you asked this yesterday, you may be using a dinosaur compiler with implicit int, then forgot to include some header file.

Comment: You did not specified at which line you have the error

Comment: Also, exposing local `static` read/write variables through pointers is horrible API. Either the user should modify something or they shouldn't. If they should modify it, then why not use caller allocation instead.

Comment: Also, "yoda conditions" went obsolete in 1989. Turbo C or later compilers can issue diagnostics for accidental assignments inside if conditions. So we no longer need to outsource our C programming to Yoda.

Comment: Regarding edit, `*(GetParams())` gives you a "lvalue", the struct itself. You no longer have a pointer then, so you can't do `->`, you would have to do `.`. This still doesn't exaplain the compiler error though, only using a dinosaur C90 compiler would explain the error.

Comment: @Lundin I don't understant what is a dinosaur C90 compiler ?

Comment: C90 is the original C standard which was active from 1990 to 1999. If you are using a compiler which is 20-30 years old, it contains all the C language flaws from that time.

Comment: In the statement that you noted `->` will be evaluated before `*` based on operator precedence.  This may not be the actual problem, but it contradicts your expected behavior noted in the last paragraph of the question.